# Are "Create Table worksheet2 as (Select * from worksheet1)" type SQL queries supported from Excel environment using only Excel ODBC/ADO driver?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Would like to simply create one Excel 2010 worksheet from another just by submitting an SQL query (from Excel VBA), e.g., without the need for follow-up VBA against a recordset. Can't find a working example or documentation from Microsoft that it's just not possible Thanks!

Comment: Try to use macro recorder ;).

Comment: Why not just copy the worksheet with VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add( _
      SourceType:=0, _
      Source:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=xxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxx;Data Source=yourServerNameOrIP;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;" _
        , "Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=yourPcName;Use Encryption for Data=False;" _
        , "Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=yourDbName") _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdTable
    .CommandText = Array("""yourDbName"".""dbo"".""yourTableName""")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .SourceConnectionFile = "C:\xxxxxxxxx.odc"
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table__._yourDbName_yourTableName"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

As I record a macro.